# initializer_list not working in VC10

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, initializer-list, visual-c++-2010

i wrote this program in VC++ 2010:

```
class class1
{
public:
 class1 (initializer_list<int> a){};
 int foo;
 float Bar;
};
void main()
{
 class1 c = {2,3};
 getchar();
}
```

but i get this errors when i compile project:

> Error 1 error C2552: 'c' :
>   non-aggregates cannot be initialized
>   with initializer
>   list c:\users\pswin\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2010\projects\test_c++0x\test_c++0x\main.cpp 27

and

> 2 IntelliSense: initialization with
>   '{...}' is not allowed for object of
>   type
>   "class1" c:\users\pswin\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2010\projects\test_c++0x\test_c++0x\main.cpp 27

what is the problem?

Comment: it sounds like you need to be using arrays for this feature... "aggregates" just really sounds like that... :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It shouldn't be supported [at all](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/533464/the-initializer-list-header-in-the-vc10-release-candidate):

> [...] the C++0x Core Language feature of initializer lists and the associated Standard Library changes weren't implemented in VC10.

The error message refers to the pre-C++0x feature of aggregate initialization, which allows the initialization of certain user-defined types by using curly braces:

```
struct pair { int first; char second; };
pair p = { 0, 'c' };
```

Aggregates are defined in *§8.5.1*:

> An aggregate is an array or a class (clause 9) with no user-declared constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members (clause 11), no base classes (clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).
>
> When an aggregate is initialized the initializer can contain an initializer-clause consisting of a brace- enclosed, comma-separated list of initializer-clauses for the members of the aggregate, written in increasing subscript or member order. If the aggregate contains subaggregates, this rule applies recursively to the members of the subaggregate.