# private member array initialization through constructor initializer's list in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, initializer-list

After going through all the questions asked about aggregate member initialization through initializer list still i am left with the question mark??? i have tried these two methods to initialize the private member array.

```
class C {
  C(const vector<int> &a): m_array(a) {} // using vector 
 private:
  C(initializer_list<int> a): m_array(a) {} //using initializer list
  int m_array[6];
};
```

both of the above methods throw error *"cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays"* in visual studio 2010. can somebody explain that whether these ways are correct, if yes then why these errors are coming up...

Comment: This is a `C++11` feature, and is not supported in VS2010. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792028/initializer-list-not-working-in-vc10

Comment: @Cyber It doesn't matter it is not legal in c++11 either. As Vlad said, arrays do not have constructors with parameters.

Comment: @luk32 You are correct, their use was incorrect either way. I was just noting that they should not be using initializer lists at all in this version of VS.

Comment: @luk32 - Always matters to know the compiler's C++ 11 completeness.

Comment: @SChepurin Seriously? What would it change?

Comment: @luk32 - Seriously. For you, probably nothing. For others, can save time struggling to compile code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say m_array(a). For this to be valid, m_array should be an object of some class say ArrayClass, which should have a parametrized constructor that accepts argument as you specified.

Now in your case, the m_array represents pointer to first element of the array m_array[]. Its quite simple to say that the constructors are called for objects and not for pointers. Writing m_array(a) means you want to do m_array = a, which is fundamentally wrong as array is allocated on stack and its base address can not be modified and you are trying to modify the array's base address.

What you can do is

1. take a vector as member and that vector's constructor will take care
   of copying the elements.
2. write your own array class.
3. use a pointer (shallow copy)

Answer (score 3):

Both these constructions require that arrays would have constructors with one parameter of type either `std::vector<int>` or `std::initializer_list<int>`. However arrays are aggregates. They have no constructor with parameter.

You should initialize the array in the bodies of the constructors.

One of approaches is to declare pointer to the first element of an array as the parameter and inside the body of the constructor to copy elements in the data member array.

For example

```
C( const int *a, size_t n )
{
   std::copy_n( a, std::min<size_t>( n, 6 ), array );
}
```

The other way is to use standard class std::array. For example

```
std::array<int, 6> array;

C( std::array<int, 6> ): array(a) {}
```

In the last case the constructor can be called as

```
C( { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 } );
```

.

Comment: i tried doing initializing in the constructor body as well even with the simplest way as "arr = {31,41}" it was not working same error persists i just want to know the reason behind it in more explanatory way.

Comment: @user3625742 Arrays have no the assignment operator.

Comment: @Neha isnt arr a pointer? And the array INITIALIZATION is done at declaration time and that too using arr[]={1,2,3};